# Is it grammatically correct to ask, "How to do something?"

Tags: grammar, questions

> "How to list files in a directory in C?"
>
> "How to avoid special char(*,%,^..) in keydown event?"
>
> "How to texture a quad in Gtk?"
>
> "How to stop the title bar from blocking the main thread in Metal?"

These are all examples of questions/comments I could/have seen on StackOverflow. Is the complete sentence, "How to do something?" wrong? I doesn't sound right, but is it wrong?

How to ask how to do something correctly?

Comment: I wouldn't call it right or wrong. It's just not a sentence. Nor is it an interrogative sentence. This makes the presence of the question mark look quite strange.

Comment: @IsabelArcher What I mean is as an interrogative sentence.

Comment: It isn't an interrogative sentence. For example, there's no subject. "How _do you_ list files in a directory in C?" would be a sentence.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Ah. I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: They look like titles to questions to me.  Sort of like headlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the difference between a main clause and a content clause, and a tensed vs infinitival interrogative construction.

Interrogative main clause :

> **How does one list** files in a directory in C?

Interrogative content clause:

> Please tell me **how one lists** files in a directory in C.

The subordinate clause above is tensed - it has a a primary verb form.

Infinitival interrogative clause:

> Please tell me **how to list** files in a directory in C.

Here we have an infinitival interrogative clause. These are allowed as subordinates only - where interrogative content clauses are allowed. (CaGEL p1264)

Since it's so prevalent on the internet, using the subordinate infinitival interrogative without a matrix clause might have slipped into informal use, but it would not be accepted as grammatical in any serious conversation or publication.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

These are not questions. These are relative infinitives, like *what to order, who to tell, when to leave,* or *which one to pick*. Putting a question mark after them does not make them questions. Relative infinitives are often used in lists, like journalists' bullet points: *what, where, when, how, who, why, ..*

They can be used as embedded question complement clauses, with the right verbs and constructions:

- *He asked her what to do.*
- *She knows when to do it.*
- *How to make sure it works is a problem.*

But they aren't questions by themselves.  There are several ways to make questions in English, but these are sposta be *Wh*-questions. There's really only one way to make them, and it doesn't involve infinitives. Here's the rule:

1. Start with a statement that has a missing or unknown part you want to ask about, e.g,
   *You can list files in Directory A **by using Program ??***
2. Substitute the appropriate *Wh*-word for the missing part, e.g,
   *You can list files in Directory A **how***
3. Form a *Yes/No* question from the modified statement, e.g,
   *Can you list files in Directory A **how**?*
4. Move the *Wh*-word to the beginning of the *Yes/No* question, e.g,
   ***How*** can you list files in Directory A?

Note that the question has its subject (*you*) and its first auxiliary inverted (*can you* instead of *you can*). It doesn't use *to*.

Infinitives with *to* are strictly subordinate clauses. **But**, in posters, advertisements, slogans, songs, bullet lists, raps, movies, slideshows, poems, and other spontaneous or artistic language, grammar does not constrain.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are grammatically incorrect, because the are sentence fragments. However, I wouldn't call them "wrong", because there is no rule that says that the titles of the questions in stack overflow have to be 100% grammatically correct. They get the poster's meaning across in a clear and concise way.

Comment: Thanks for reply